# Unable to see data in CDA

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde, pentaho-ctools

[image]

I am Trying to genrate dashboard using pentaho CDE.

- I am using SQL jndi for database.
- I wanted to genrate dial chart for given value from drop down.

I have designed the front end. when I try to load data from sql in CDA I am geeting error as shown in the picture "please select Data Access ID".

Please provide help for this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the server logs? There's probably an error there that will give you some clue of what's wrong.